# How can you have each button/link on a page execute it's own action in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with C#. Per the requirements for an application I've developed, each view has several buttons that execute the same Controller Post action. Currently, to know what button was clicked when the action was posted, I am using a hidden field on the form called PageAction. This field is set with a value when any button is clicked. This has caused a fair amount of issues in the controller implementation of the POST action for this view because I have to do a case statement against the value submitted via PageAction. It's one of those things that seems like it could be done better and simpler.

Is there a way to have multiple actions for a single view? This way each button would post the form to it's own controller action (yet all of these would correlate to the same view). I'd like to get away from the "magic string" checking on the PageAction value; however, all of these buttons are part of the same html form so I'm not sure how this would be possible aside from splitting each button into it's own form or having each button dynamically change where the form posts to. Both of the latter options sound like they'd be more complicated than what I am already doing.

All suggestions/comments are welcomed. Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I've gone through the blog post linked here: http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/  and replicated the functionality, but I was wondering...how would this work if the button names on a page are standardized across several different pages in an application? The blog post seems to assume distinct button names matching the action name in the controller, but in my case this won't be unique enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/) useful which illustrates the usage of a custom [ActionNameSelectorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameselectorattribute.aspx).

Comment: Deleted my answer, was same method to select as Darin, this is the way to go, similar to selecting actions for Post/Get, use this to filter on your post data.

Comment: Thanks for this link Darin. I've gone through the blog post and replicated the functionality, but I was wondering...how would this work if the button names on a page are standardized across several different pages? The blog post seems to assume distinct button names matching the action name in the controller, but in my case this won't be unique enough. I'll add this comment to the question itself. It turned out longer than I expected.

Comment: @Jason, well you could modify the names of those buttons to match the action names on your controllers.

Comment: Here's an example. The application is sort of like a wizard. You go from screen A --> B --> C --> D --> etc with no jumping around. Screens B and C have standard buttons: Previous and Next. Changing the name of these buttons on each view won't make sense. Does that clarify the issue a bit more?

Comment: @Jason, no it doesn't clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be considering them AJAX calls instead of form posts?  This is what most people do if they want to do different actions on the same page.